# Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rollupjs

I am facing an error while running the server after creating a vite application please help me resolve this.

[image]

I was learning threejs and just created a vite application with vanilla framework and javascript as the language , it was all created smoothly but npm run dev shows the error which i cant seem to resolve.

I tried installing .json file after removing but still no good.

Answer (score 6):

You can try "npm install vite@4.4.0" or "npm install vite@4.0.0", it will solve the issue